# Sending a queue through a constructor in java?

Tags: java, list, stack, queue

The goal is to pass a data structure(queue) through a constructor and return a new queue once it goes through a method. I created a method of type Queue that converts from infix to postfix order. The problem is, when I pass the queue through the constructor, I am outputting all 'a's instead of the equation itself. So, I know that the linked list is passing the LENGTH of the queue, but not the characters themselves. 
Output:

```
a+b+c/(d+f)
aaaaaaaaaaa
```

Main Class:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
class Convert
{

    static int Prec(char ch)
    {
        switch (ch)
        {
        case '+':
        case '-':
            return 1;

        case '*':
        case '/':
            return 2;

        case '^':
            return 3;
        }
        return -1;
    }


    public static QueueADT infixToPostFix(QueueADT in)
    {
        QueueADT infix = in;
        QueueADT result = new QueueADT();
        StackADT stack = new StackADT();

        while(infix.empty() == false)
        {
            char c = infix.dequeue();

            if (Character.isLetterOrDigit(c))
                result.enqueue(c);

            else if (c == '(')
                stack.push(c);


            else if (c == ')')
            {
                while (!stack.empty() && stack.peek() != '(')
                    result.enqueue(stack.pop());

                stack.pop();
            }
            else // an operator is encountered
            {
                while (!stack.empty() && Prec(c) <= Prec(stack.peek()))
                    result.enqueue(stack.pop());
                stack.push(c);
            }

        }

        // pop all the operators from the stack
        while (!stack.empty())
            result.enqueue(stack.pop());

        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        QueueADT infix = new QueueADT();
        String str = "a+b+c/(d+f)";
        for(int i=0; i < str.length(); i++)
        {
            infix.enqueue(str.charAt(i));
            System.out.print(str.charAt(i));
        }
        QueueADT postfix = infixToPostFix(infix);
        System.out.println();
        while(!postfix.empty())
        {
            System.out.print(postfix.dequeue());
        }
    }
}
```

Queue Class:

```
public class QueueADT 
{
    private int size;
    private Node front;
    private Node rear;

    public QueueADT()
    {
        size = 0;
        front = null;
        rear = null;
    }

    public boolean empty()
    {
        return(size == 0);
    }
    public int size()
    {
        return size;
    }
    public void enqueue(char character)
    {
        Node newNode = new Node();
        newNode.setData(character);
        newNode.setNext(null);
        if(this.empty())
        {
            front = newNode;
        }
        else
            rear.setNext(newNode);
        rear = newNode;
        size++;
    }
    public char dequeue()
    {
        char i;
        i = front.getData();
        size--;
        if(this.empty())
            rear = null;
        return i;
    }
    public char front()
    {
        return front.getData();
    }
}
```

Stack class:

```
public class StackADT 
{
    private Node top;
    private int size;
    public StackADT()
    {
        top = null;
        size = 0;
    }
    public boolean empty()
    {
        return (top == null);
    }
    public char peek()
    {
        return top.getData();
    }
    public int size()
    {
        return size;
    }
    public void push(char character)
    {
        Node newNode = new Node();
        newNode.setData(character);
        newNode.setNext(top);
        top = newNode;
        size++;
    }
    public char pop()
    {
        char i;
        i = top.getData();
        top = top.getNext();
        size--;
        return i;
    }
    public int onTop()
    {
        char i = pop();
        push(i);
        return i;
    }
}
```

Node class:

```
public class Node 
{
    private char data;
    private Node next;

    public Node()
    {
        data = 0;
        next = null;
    }
    public Node(char d)
    {
        data = d;
    }
    public Node(char d, Node n)
    {
        data = d;
        next = n;
    }
    public void setData(char newData)
    {
        data = newData;
    }
    public void setNext(Node newNext)
    {
        next = newNext;
    }
    public char getData()
    {
        return data;
    }
    public Node getNext()
    {
        return next;
    }
    public void displayNode()
    {
        System.out.print(data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your implementation of dequeue method in QueueADT class is incorrect. You never change field "front", that's why when you call that method in your case, 'a' is always being returned. Add
    `front = front.getNext();`
after line
    `char i = front.getData();`
There are more problems with that code - try testing each of your methods separately, not only the program as a whole.